# Google places Api result different from Uber or OLA result

Tags: android, android-studio, google-places-autocomplete

I am using `PlaceAutocomplete` for getting all the location and I have open default autocomplete location intent by using the following:

```
Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_FULLSCREEN)
                .build(this);
startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

I am getting result that are different from UBER or OLA.

So anybody knows why results are different from UBER and OLA.

Thanks!

Comment: may be they using AutocompleteFilter to filter the results

Comment: I already used that one. It again give me same result as of defalut auto complete location Intent.  .

Comment: you can use filter in intent, AutocompleteFilter countryFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
                .setCountry("IN")
                .build();   Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_FULLSCREEN)
                .setFilter(countryFilter)
                .build(this);